# Restoring Chrome Session from index.dat files

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browsing, session-restore

I had 50 tabs open in Chrome, that I lost due to unfortunate reasons, from 4th July, 2020. Since then, I have stopped using Chrome, trying not to overwrite the Last Tabs files, but Chrome has been opened and shut down more than once.

I do see a session storage folder, where a .ldb file dated 4th July, 2020...2nd July, 2020 exist. My question is, is it possible to restore at least some of the tabs from those dates, from these files?

Any help would be appreciated. I'm willing to take a few risks with the operating system here. History of that time has also been deleted.

Thank you in advance. Please help

Comment: Why not just use Ctl-H to open the history and open the Tabs from tehre?

Comment: History of that time has been removed as well. I want to restore the session, and I thought the LDB files might help since they weren't empty